# Is there an isometry from $\Bbb R$ to $\{(x,y) \mid x,y\in \Bbb R, y= x^2\}$

Tags: real-analysis, isometry

I think there is not, but I do not know how. I try to start with the simplest point $0$, and assume that $f(0) = a$ then $|f(x) - f(0)|=|x|$, but I do not know how to get a contradiction.

in $\{(x,y) \mid x,y\in \Bbb R, y= x^2\}$ the metric is the standard Euclidean metric from $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: An isometry is a function between two metric spaces. I suppose that you use the standard distance in $\mathbb{R}$ but what distance are you using in the graph of $y=x^2$?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. On the line, $a < b < c$ implies something about the distance from $a$ to $c$.

Hint. What can you say about the "triangle" **in**equality for three sides of the triangle with vertices $a$, $b$ and $c$?. What about the triangle with vertices $f(a)$, $f(b)$ and $f(c)$.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: @Adam See the second hint.

Comment: $|c-a|=|f(c)-f(a)| \leqslant |f(c)-f(0)|+|f(0)-f(a)|$but there is no contradiction

Comment: @Adam I expanded the second hint. Working with $f(0)$ is not helpful. I could solve the problem for you but you will feel better and learn more when you get it for yourself.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much!!!